# Using the Rect object on Android

Tags: android, size, ondraw, rect

I am playing around on my android emulator trying to recreate a game. So first thing, I create the background image. I used my professors template on another piece of code to help me load in the background. All it is is a Bitmap image that takes the size of the entire screen, but in his code he imports the Rect class to first resize the image and then places it into the actual onDraw. I initially thought that this was repetitive if I am only going to create one background, but when I comment the Rect initialization out in my code, the background image doesn't even load on the emulator. So my question is, WHY do you have to create a Rect object/initializer first and then fill in the actual image in the onDraw with the new sizes for it to show up?

Sample of my Code:

```
Rect backgroundDimensions = new Rect(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight); 
canvas.drawBitmap(background,null,backgroundDimensions,paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to use a Rect for drawing a bitmap to a canvas, there are many overloads of the method drawBitmap [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) in the canvas class

Comment: That's why I'm confused, because several times I would comment out the Rect portion and the project screen on my emulator would just be white as if the background wasn't being added. I was just curious to if there was an actual explanation for that that I should learn

Comment: how does your canvas.drawBitmap look when you comment out Rect?

Comment: well I have to change the sizes back obviously instead of null and the Rect name, but it doesn't show anything on my emulator screen. It seems as if i HAVE to add a Rect object

Comment: did you try canvas.drawBitmap(background,0,0,null);